# How to use custom filter on ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My select tag which has options which takes from object.

```
contacts = [{'Id' : 1 , 'type' : "person,occupation"},
            {'Id': 2 , 'type' : "student,school"}]

<select ng-model="typeId" id="contactType" ng-init="typeId=1" ng-change="change()" ng-options="item.value as item.type for item in contacts" >

    // my custom filter 

module.filter("splitString", ['Service', function (Service) {
        return function (value) {
        var s =[];
           if(value.type!=null)
                s = value.type.split(",");
               else
              return '';
        if (Service.getvalue()) {
            return s[0];   
        }
        else {
            return s[1];
        }
       };
 }]);
```

> Service.getvalue() returns boolean value so accordingly i need to
>   spilt the comma seperated string but when i use this filter it gives
>   $digest iteration limit error

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do here. Do you want to use the 'splitString' in the ng-options ? If so can you explain what that var s = []; is used for?

Comment: opps my bad....

s = value.type.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer :

```
    var services = smthg; // put here what you want to filter
    var filteredServices = services.filter(function(service){
        if(service.getvalue()) {
          return s[0];
        }
        else {
          return s[1];
        }
    }
```